# $dirty flag setting to true when value entered in text box but not vice versa

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form in which

```
myForm.$dirty
```

gets set to true when i enter a value in text box

```
<input name="input" ng-model="myModel.text">
```

But the flag isn't setting to false when i delete all values from text box.
Why is it so and how to rectify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$dirty` means you've interacted with the form, so once you've typed anything, it's considered dirty.

Starting with version 1.1.1, theres a `$setPristine` function that will allow you restore a form to its pristine state, but for the moment, you'll have to figure out a workaround that fits your needs.

Comment: Well, yes. You could always just do `myForm.$dirty = false` upon certain conditions. The problem is it's more complicated than that, especially when forms are nested, which Angular allows for. Angular has a `$setDirty` function it uses to mark dirty forms, which bubbles up through the parents. Just setting the attribute directly wouldn't necessarily keep everything linked together, hence the new `$setPristine` function in 1.1.1 which will take care of that for you.

Comment: Here is an example of how to use it from another question: http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview. Here is a link to the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759221/angularjs-setpristine-to-reset-form