# AngularJs .$setPristine to reset form

Tags: angularjs

I been struggling to reset form once form is submitted. Someone posted this [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/charms/AhGDC/24/) which I want to make it work but no success. Here is my [My Code Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ukdAGn?p=preview).

`$scope.form.$setPristine();` is not setting `Pristine: {{user_form.$pristine}}` to **true**. See example above.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think part of the problem is that data.name is getting cleared out of the regular angular way.  What if you declare data in your model and actually use $scope.data.name = '' within the reset method.  Otherwise, you could try $scope.apply();  I think the model is still dirty and that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

$setPristine() was introduced in the 1.1.x branch of angularjs.  You need to use that version rather than 1.0.7 in order for it to work.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/815Bml?p=preview

Comment: You are right. One Question. When will this be added to stable version. any idea or will it be used in 1.0.x branch?. 1.1.5 is not stable.

Comment: I'm not sure when they will make 1.1.x stable.

Comment: @Rashid Angular 1.2 will be the next stable version (whenever it's released). All of the 1.1.x versions are subject to API changes, but you'll have to deal with those same changes when moving from 1.0.x to 1.2.x anyway.

Answer (score 15):

Had a similar problem, where I had to set the form back to pristine, but also to untouched, since $invalid and $error were both used to show error messages. Only using setPristine() was not enough to clear the error messages.

I solved it by using setPristine() and setUntouched().
(See Angular's documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

So, in my controller, I used:

```
$scope.form.setPristine(); 
$scope.form.setUntouched();
```

These two functions reset the complete form to $pristine and back to $untouched, so that all error messages were cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In my case it was form.$setPristine() and form.$setUntouched().

Comment: They should have made a single function available to do a complete reset

Answer (score 14):

Just for those who want to get `$setPristine` without having to upgrade to v1.1.x, here is the function I used to simulate the `$setPristine` function. I was reluctant to use the v1.1.5 because one of the AngularUI components I used is no compatible.

```
var setPristine = function(form) {
    if (form.$setPristine) {//only supported from v1.1.x
        form.$setPristine();
    } else {
        /*
         *Underscore looping form properties, you can use for loop too like:
         *for(var i in form){ 
         *  var input = form[i]; ...
         */
        _.each(form, function (input) {
            if (input.$dirty) {
                input.$dirty = false;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Note that it ONLY makes `$dirty` fields clean and help changing the 'show error' condition like `$scope.myForm.myField.$dirty && $scope.myForm.myField.$invalid`.

Other parts of the form object (like the css classes) still need to consider, but this solve my problem: hide error messages.

Answer (score 7):

There is another way to pristine **form** that is by sending form into the controller. For example:-

**In view:-**

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="addUser(myForm)" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-mode="user.name"/>
     <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.name.$dirty && myForm.name.$invalid">
      <span ng-show="myForm.name.$error.required">Name is required.</span>
    </span>

    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Add User</button>
</form>
```

**In Controller:-**

```
$scope.addUser = function(myForm) {
       myForm.$setPristine();
};
```

Answer (score 6):

[DavidLn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053002/1203824) has worked well for me in the past. But it doesn't capture all of setPristine's functionality, which tripped me up this time. Here is a fuller shim:

```
var form_set_pristine = function(form){
    // 2013-12-20 DF TODO: remove this function on Angular 1.1.x+ upgrade
    // function is included natively

    if(form.$setPristine){
        form.$setPristine();
    } else {
        form.$pristine = true;
        form.$dirty = false;
        angular.forEach(form, function (input, key) {
            if (input.$pristine)
                input.$pristine = true;
            if (input.$dirty) {
                input.$dirty = false;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same problem of having to reset a form at its pristine state in Angular version 1.0.7 (no $setPristine method)

In my use case, the form, after being filled and submitted must disappear until it is again necessary for filling another record. So I made the show/hide effect by using ng-switch instead of ng-show. As I suspected, with ng-switch, the form DOM sub-tree is completely removed and later recreated. So the pristine state is automatically restored.

I like it because it is simple and clean but it may not be a fit for anybody's use case.

it may also imply some performance issues for big forms (?) In my situation I did not face this problem yet.