# angular-wizard - having issue with clearing form inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular-wizard to make multiple passes at collecting some basic form data.
This wizard has 3 steps: the first step collect customer's name and number, and the second step collects customer's address and contact person. When all steps are finished, I'm saving the collected data to the local storage, and set the wizard back to its first page.
The issue I'm having is that both of my text input controls on the first wizard page retain their value from the past run. I'm asking for help with resetting those fields back to '' values. All fields in this wizard form are bound to the $scope.currentCustomer object variables.
Here is my html:

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <h3 class="text-muted">wizard</h3>
</div>

<div>
    {{wizardPageMessage}}
    <wizard>
        <wz-step title="Step 1">
            <h1>This is Step 1</h1>
            <!--<ng-include src="'step1.html'"></ng-include>-->
            <input id="custName" placeholder="customer name" data-ng-model="currentCustomer.customerName"/>
            <br/>
            <input id="custNumber" placeholder="customer number" data-ng-model="currentCustomer.customerNumber"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" wz-next value="Proceed to Next Step"
                   data-ng-click="page_1_Action(currentCustomer.customerName,currentCustomer.customerNumber)" />
        </wz-step>
        <wz-step title="Step 2">
            <h1>This is Step 2</h1>
            <input id="custAddress" placeholder="customer address" data-ng-model="currentCustomer.customerAddress"/>
            <br/>
            <input id="custContact" placeholder="customer contact" data-ng-model="currentCustomer.customerContact"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" wz-next value="Proceed to Next Step"
                   data-ng-click="addCustomerAddressAndContact(currentCustomer.customerAddress,currentCustomer.customerContact)"/>
        </wz-step>
        <wz-step title="Step 3">
            <h1>This is Step 3</h1>
            <p>Finish this round, and start a new one</p>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" wz-next value="Commit And Start Over" data-ng-click="saveCustomerRecord()"/>
        </wz-step>
    </wizard>
</div>

<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Here is my App and controller code:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('wizardApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'mgo-angular-wizard'
]);

app.value('host', false /*use local host*/ ? "http://localhost:63428" : "http://sampleservice.breezejs.com");

app.controller('MainCtrl',
    ['$scope', 'logger', 'datacontext','$timeout','WizardHandler',
        function($scope, logger, datacontext, $timeout,WizardHandler) {
            var currentCustomer;
            function Customer(name,number,address,contact)
            {
                this.customerName = name;
                this.customerNumber = number;
                this.customerAddress = address;
                this.customerContact = contact;
            }

            logger.log('created MainCtrl');
            $scope.items = [];
            $scope.logList = logger.logList;
            $scope.lastLog = function(){return logger.lastLog;};

            $scope.page_1_Action = function(name,number){
                 logger.log('MainCtrl : page_1_Action dataInput:  ' + name + '  ' + number);

                 $scope.currentCustomer = new Customer('','','','');
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerName = name;
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerNumber = number;
                    }
            $scope.addCustomerAddressAndContact = function(address,contact){
                logger.log('MainCtrl : addCustomerAddressAndContact dataInput:  ' + address + '   ' + contact);
                $scope.currentCustomer.customerAddress = address;
                $scope.currentCustomer.customerContact = contact;
                    }
            $scope.saveCustomerRecord = function(){
                 datacontext.addCustomer($scope.currentCustomer);
                 datacontext.commit();
                 datacontext.showExported();

                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerName = '';
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerNumber = '';
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerAddress = '';
                 $scope.currentCustomer.customerContact = '';
                 WizardHandler.wizard().goTo(0);
            }

        }]

);

app
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Comment: Check out $setPristine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759221/angularjs-setpristine-to-reset-form

Comment: Even after I've wrapped the entire Wizard into a form tag, $scope.form.setPrestine() did not change anything :(

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Can't get it working in a Plunkr, seems hacky, but could you increment the scope everytime the commit button is hit? Then change the form model bindings. Ie. model="currentCustomer2.name" $scope.currentCustomer2. =\

Comment: Not sure how exactly to do this increment. Any chance you could have a plunkr example, please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I managed to reset the values. My controller looks like:

```
function TripController($scope, WizardHandler) {
  'use strict';

  $scope.trip = new Trip();


  $scope.addTrip = function () {
    // ...
  }

  $scope.finished = function () {
    this.addTrip ();
    this.trip = new Trip();
    WizardHandler.wizard().goTo(0);
  }
}
```

My Trip class:

```
function Trip(title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

And my template is:

```
<h2>New trip</h2>

<wizard on-finish="finished()">
  <wz-step title="Start">
    <h3>Trip details</h3>
    <ng-form name="part1">
      <input ng-model="trip.title" ng-required="true">
    </ng-form>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" wz-next="" ng-disabled="part1.$invalid">Next</a>
    </p>

  </wz-step>
  <wz-step>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" wz-next="">Next</a>
    </p>
  </wz-step>

</wizard>
```