# Angular Validation NG-message dont show required after submit and erase text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

This is my current validation set up for my form

```
<ng-messages for="searchForm.$error" ng-if="searchForm.$submitted">
  <ng-message when="required" class="error-message">This search field is required.</ng-message>
</ng-messages>
```

and my form

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="searchForm.$valid && searchcode()" name="searchForm" novalidate>
```

It works fine.

But here is what I don't like this scenario

1) Hit Enter on empty searchbox - > it shows the correct message "Field Is Required"

2) Start Typing and Erase Text without hitting enter - > it shows error message again

It's the second scenario I dont want...any ideas ?

Comment: why are you using `searchForm.searchQuery.$touched`? this might be the reason you're getting this behaviour. try using just `searchForm.$submitted`

Comment: Got rid of it and just had submitted but same behaviour...it seems like after the first submit the form stays in "Submitted" state, and that error message just shows whenever the textbox is empty then rather when submitted again

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759221/angularjs-setpristine-to-reset-form) might help you.

Comment: Also a fiddle demo would help.

Comment: I also think, that if you replace the $touched part in the ng-if with $pristine. Make sure you set the form with $setPristine after submitting the form.

Comment: you can do : `<ng-message when="required" ng-if="!searchForm.searchQuery.$touched" `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe your field name for the error message is not right.
Cannot tell the exact reason why yours not work because you did not provide an example.
However, when I tested, it works fine.

```
 <form ng-controller="MyCtrl" role="form" name="searchForm" novalidate
    ng-submit="searchcode()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" 
      ng-keypress="searchForm.$submitted=false"
      required minlength="5" />
    <ng-messages ng-if="searchForm.$submitted"
      for="searchForm.myField.$error">
      <ng-message when="required" class="error-message">
        This search field is required.
      </ng-message>
    </ng-messages>
  </form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/56koY7YxPDVFe4S26x9N?p=preview

Comment: Same thing happens on yours. So you hit enter without any text and the enter message displayes i.e. "Enter Required Field" then just type something and clear the text in the textfield and the error message will display again without having entered submit

Comment: Oh, you want to display the error message only if submit button is pressed? Then, simply add `ng-keypress="searchForm.$submitted=false"` to the input field although it's not the best. I modified the `plnkr` for that.

Comment: Only want to show the message if the textbox is empty and the submit button is pressed

Comment: Now it seems to display the error message on any submit even if there is a value

Comment: Simply comment out `//$scope.field="";` in searchcode() function. For advanced key control, you may look into use ng-keyup. I have to tell you that you can make it work if you keep asking, but I don't see it's the best. The best I think is `when you want to show message based on submit, the message better to be from server-side` although you may disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I will do this in different way. Hope it helps. It will show the messages if the form is not valid and dirty. When the user submits, reset the form by setting it to be pristine. With this, you can reset you $scope.field to empty and not showing error messages.

```
<form ng-controller="MyCtrl" role="form" name="searchForm" novalidate ng-submit="searchcode()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="field" name="myField" required minlength="5" />
   <p class="error-message" ng-show="!searchForm.$valid && searchForm.$dirty">
     This search field is required.
   </p> 
   <ul>
      <li>$submitted : {{searchForm.$submitted}}
      <li>$valid: {{searchForm.$valid}}
      <li>$dirty:  {{searchForm.$dirty}} 
   </ul>
</form>
```

On submit, reset the form by setting it to be pristine.

```
$scope.searchcode = function() {
    $scope.searchForm.$setPristine();
    $scope.field="";
    console.log('submitted');
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/m0cCmOAtY2J8fhSv0DVg?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own custom validator, and then use an if statement to decide what to validate.  Since for instance you don't want there to be any validation done when a person is erasing characters, you could write the validator so that it takes an event and then you can get the char code of the key that fired the event, opting not to validate when that char code represents either backspace or delete.